# How to stop automatic download of PDF in mobile browser

Tags: mobile, pdf

I have created a website (still under development).

While I am directing to a PDF link in the mobile browser it is automatically being downloaded instead of opening in a new window like desktop browser.

How to make it open like desktop browser instead of automatic download?

Comment: Related to the technical restriction on Android.SE: [Why are all Android web browsers unable to display PDF documents?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/249363/44325), [Open PDF files directly in Chrome for Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230250/44325).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[buxik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3180233/buxik)'s answer from [How to display a PDF via Android web browser without "downloading" first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437602/how-to-display-a-pdf-via-android-web-browser-without-downloading-first) looks like a good solution:

> You can open a file PDF in Google Docs Viewer by appending the URL to:
>
> ```
> https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=<URL of a supported doc>
> ```
>
> This would open a PDF file in the default browser or a WebView.
>
> A list of supported formats is given [here](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1738646)

Answer (score 3):

This is by design. Each app does one such function.I dont think its possible.

There is nothing you can do on your website. There may be browser that hss this function. But the common ones don't  do this- Chrome, Firefox, Samsung, Quant etc.